# Android service turns red

Tags: java, android, intentservice

I want to add a service to my manifest but it gives a warning in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aura_apps.tygo_asbroek.intentexample" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".TygoIntentService"
    >
    </service>
</application>
```

Here is the Java code:

```
package com.aura_apps.tygo_asbroek.intentexample;

public class TygoIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "com.bluelionapps.intentexample";

    public TygoIntentService(String name) {
        super("TygoIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //This is what the service does
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Lauched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Here you see my complete Manifest but `.TygoIntentService` says `TygoIntentService.java` doesn't have a default constructor of my app. If i run it, it's just working but I want to know if this can give any problems in the future and if it gives one what i need to do.

Comment: "TygoIntentService says TygoIntentService.java doesn't have a default constructer my app" -- please post the code for `TygoIntentService`, then.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `String name` parameter from the constructor:

```
public TygoIntentService() {
    super("TygoIntentService");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use/need the name String there, just remove the constructor, and let the compiler add it behind scenes by default.